# Empty text view message when listview is empty

Tags: android, android-listview

I have a ListView with an empty list catch in the XML and it works fine. How to toggle ListView Empty Text please ?

This is my XML code :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/empty"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/emptyList" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        /> 

</LinearLayout>
```

I'm not using a ListActivity. It s possible to do that please ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to make use of [`setEmptyView(View v)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.html#setEmptyView%28android.view.View%29):

```
person_ListView.setEmptyView(root.findViewById(R.id.empty));
```

*offtopic*: `ListActivity` is using this method also, but with `android.R.id.empty`.

Comment: In fact, I want to hide the title of the listview also when it is empty

Comment: You're only getting answers for what you're asking in question, not in the comments ... set the title visibility to GONE